# Inserting a stop statement

Tags: python

How can I get this program to stop at when the number **13** is entered?

```
print "\t:-- Enter a Multiplication --: \n"
x = ("Enter the first number: ")                                    
y = ("Enter your second number to multiply by: ")

for total in range(1, 12):
        x = input("Enter a number: ")
        y = input("Multiplied by this: ")
        print "\n  TOTAL: "
        print x, "X", y, "=", (x * y)


#Exits the program.
raw_input("\t\tPress Enter to Exit")
```

Comment: In english: what is your question? I don't get it.

Comment: I would like to stop the program anything after number 13 is entered.

Comment: @Will You want to stop after the thirteenth number is entered or after the number `13` is entered?

Comment: It stated above..

Comment: I want to stop at 12 to "show 12 times tables"

Comment: I think you want to adjust the `range` call arguments. Check the documentation for what the arguments mean: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Comment: use `range(1, 13)` or `range(12)` (which means `range(0, 12)`) and code in loop will be executed 12 times.

Comment: tried this doesnt do nothing tried (1, 12, 1) all that

Comment: Clarified problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do here, I think an if statement would be a better solution. Something like this:

```
print("Enter a multiplication")
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
y = int(input("Multiplied by this: "))


def multiply(x, y):
    if 1 < x < 13 and 1 < y < 13:
        answer = x * y

        print("Total:")
        print("%s X %s = %s" % (x, y, answer))
    else:
        print("Your number is out of range")

multiply(x, y)
```

But to be honest, there are quite a few parts of your code that some work.

Comment: Beautiful, I was so close too!! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You used a **for** loop; this is appropriate when you know *before you enter the loop* how many times you want to execute it.  This is not the problem you have.  Instead, use a **while** loop; this keeps going until a particular condition occurs.

Try something like this:

```
# Get the first input:
x = input("Enter a number (13 to quit): ")
# Check NOW to see whether we have to quit
while x <= 12:
    # As long as the first number is acceptable,
    #   get the second and print the product.
    y = input("Multiplied by this: ")
    print "\n  TOTAL: \n", x, "X", y, "=", (x * y)

    # Get another 'x' value before going back to the top.
    x = input("Enter a number (13 to quit): ")

# -- Here, you're done with doing products.
# -- Continue as you wish, such as printing a "times table".
```